# With unbalanced datasets are training results affected when I chose Kfold or StratifiedKFold validation?

Tags: cross-validation

As the title suggested:

With unbalanced datasets are training results affected when I chose Kfold or StratifiedKFold validation?

Intuitively, I would say yes. But what would the mathematical explanation for this? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the data is sufficiently randomized, each of the folds has many examples, and every class appears often in the dataset, using cross-validation shouldn't be problematic. This is because if there are enough examples for each class and enough examples in each fold, the central limit theorem says that the class distribution for each fold will closely approximate the class distribution over the entire dataset.

Comment: That's what I am concerned about: I have 8 classes. Some classes have 1000-2000 representattives, others only as few as 80.

Comment: It is probably best to use stratified cross-validation for your problem. Arguably it artificially reduces the variance between your per-fold estimates, but the reduced bias from increased consistency should more than make up for that. Only 80 instances some classes is a very small number for typical 10 fold CV.